# lapply to add column to existing dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames, and want to perform a function on each column in the data frame.

I've been googling for a while, but the issue I have is this:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))
df.2 <- data.frame(data=cbind(rnorm(5, 0), rnorm(5, 2), rnorm(5, 5)))

names(df.1) <- c("a", "b", "c")
names(df.2) <- c("a", "b", "c")

ls.1<- list(df.1,df.2)


res <- lapply(ls.1, function(x){
  x$d <- x$b + x$c
  return(x)
})
```

Returns a new list "res" with a group of unnamed dataframes in them (res[[1]], res[[2]] etc).

```
[[1]]
           a        b        c        d
1  2.2378686 3.640607 4.793172 8.433780
2 -0.4411046 3.690850 5.290814 8.981664
3 -1.1490879 3.081092 4.982820 8.063912
4 -0.3024211 1.929033 4.743569 6.672602
5  1.3658726 3.395564 2.800131 6.195695

[[2]]
           a        b        c         d
1  0.3452530 3.264709 7.384127 10.648836
2 -1.2031949 3.118633 4.840496  7.959129
3  0.6177369 1.119107 4.938917  6.058024
4 -1.0470713 1.942357 5.747748  7.690106
5  0.8732836 2.704501 5.805754  8.510254
```

I'm interested in adding columns to the original dataframes (df.1, df.2) How would I do this?

Comment: `res[[1]]` is `df.1` and `res[[2]]` is `df.2`

Comment: Yes, and that's great. but if I'm interested in using d I've now lost the information contained in the name of the df.1.

So for instance if df.1 was really named "cats" I can't go cats$d.

Not a problem when there is only 2 dataframes to remember but in this situation there are over 20.

Comment: You can always do `res[[1]]$d` or `lapply(res, function(x) x[["d"]])` to get all the `d` columns in the list. but what do you want to do with that?

Comment: `ls.1` is an *unnamed* list. You can do `names(ls.1) <- c("cats", "dogs")` and then the output of your `lapply` will also be named. And `res$cats$d` will work.

Comment: Rui, I think that is a good solution - but it involves creating two lists, the list of the dataframes and then the list of the names which could result in error etc. It seems like doubling up - but if that's the best way thanks!

Comment: You don't have to make an entire new df, all you have to do is name the list's members. If not named, you can always resort to `res[[1]]$d` or something similar.

Comment: `list2env` will help as said in my answer, but you have to ask yourself, if you're going to loop on those data frames, don't they belong in a list to start with ? You could keep them in a list for all your analysis, it will most probably be cleaner and easier

Comment: Another way is to list the dataframes in your workspace with `ls(pattern = "^df")`. And use this output to set `names(ls.1)`. Like this the odds of error are smaller.

Comment: Some `R` users seem to feel like putting similar objects into a list has an "overhead", that it's better and clearer to keep them apart, but the opposite is true, you'll be able to do operations such as  `my_list <- lapply(my_list, my_fun)` all along, and forget about housekeeping to keep similar objects connected through naming conventions or awkward code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name your list elements, or use `tibble::lst` which will do it for you:

```
ls.1<- list(df.1 = df.1,df.2 = df.2)
ls.2<- tibble::lst(df.1, df.2)

res1 <- lapply(ls.1, function(x){
  x$d <- x$b + x$c
  return(x)
})

res2 <- lapply(ls.2, function(x){
  x$d <- x$b + x$c
  return(x)
})

# $df.1
#            a         b        c        d
# 1  0.6782608 4.0774244 2.845351 6.922776
# 2  2.3620601 1.9395314 5.438832 7.378364
# 3 -0.5913838 2.0579972 4.312360 6.370357
# 4  0.5532147 0.8581389 5.867889 6.726027
# 5 -0.3251044 1.9838598 4.321008 6.304867
# 
# $df.2
#            a        b        c        d
# 1  1.9918131 3.195105 5.715858 8.910963
# 2  0.2525537 2.507358 5.040691 7.548050
# 3  0.5038298 3.112855 5.265974 8.378830
# 4  0.4873384 3.377182 5.685714 9.062896
# 5 -0.6539881 0.157948 5.407508 5.565456
```

To overwrite the original data.frames you can use `list2env` on the output.

Comment: Thanks Moody! The trick I hadn't realised was that you could name the list on the original creation. so df.1=df.2. That makes the list creation a lot clearer and then you can refer to it quite easily using df.list$  - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add columns, you will have to either overwrite your `ls.1` with `res` or perhaps manually assign result to your original data.frames, e.g. `df.1 <- res[[1]]`. But there are a hundred ways to skin a cat (pun intended) and there may be other better approaches.